# second view call from first view

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to call secondview from my current view but this code suggested by someone is not working properly

```
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[nav pushViewController:@"Second" animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can u provide more code to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use the presentModalViewController for the second view.

hope this will help you.

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:SecondView animated:YES];

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[self presentModalViewController:SecondView animated:YES];`?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you pushing an `NSString` onto a `UINavigationController`? I think what you want is:

```
SecondView * vc = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"SecondView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Hey @MSgambel, I think you've mixed UIView & UIViewController. :p

Comment: I figured that he called his `UIViewController` `SecondView`. Good to point that out though!

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest you put naviagtionbar initialization in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if it's your rootViewController. You can initiate it with rootViewController, like so:

   ```
   UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController_1];
   self.window.rootViewController = nav;
   [nav release];
   ```
2. Push other views in your view controller(e.g. your FirstViewController.m):

   ```
   SecondViewController * secondViewController_2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondViewController" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
   // Or: SecondViewController * secondViewController_2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] init...] autorelease];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController_2 animated:YES];
   ```